# Reorganize array for highcharts

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'banner' => 'banner1',
    'dayofweek' => '1',
    'count' => '3',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'banner' => 'banner1',
    'dayofweek' => '2',
    'count' => '1',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'banner' => 'banner2',
    'dayofweek' => '2',
    'count' => '3',
  )
)
```

I need to use it in highcharts to get two different vectors with the dayofweek as day and the count as value. This is how should be the highcharts array:

```
series:[
    {
        name:'banner1',
        data:[3,1,0,0,0,0,0,]
    },
    {
        name:'banner2',
        data:[0,3,0,0,0,0,0,]
    }
]
```

I need to have the array in this way I guess:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'banner' => 'banner1',
    'counts' => '3,1,0,0,0,0,0'
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'banner' => 'banner2',
    'counts' => '0,3,0,0,0,0,0'
  )

)
```

How can I parse the array to get the format I need?

Comment: You are getting array of arrays..while building inner-arrays instead of making them array..create object and add those of objects to array..

Comment: sorry I can't understand what you mean.

Comment: I don't quite understand what output you want - can you give an example?

Comment: I've given exactly the array as I want, watch the last block code.

Comment: It is not related with highcharts, but with parsing data in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what you need is something like this:

```
$initialArray = ...;
$temp = array();
foreach ($initialArray AS $a) {
    if (!isset($temp[ $a['banner'] ])) {
        $temp[ $a['banner'] ] = array_fill(0, 7, 0);
    }
    $temp[ $a['banner'] ][ $a['dayofweek'] - 1 ] = intval($a['count']);
}

$series = array();
foreach ($temp AS $banner => $counts) {
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->banner = $banner;
    $obj->counts = $counts;
    $series[] = $obj;
}

echo json_encode($series);
```

It can be optimized to use less memory. But if you have not too much data (not millions of banners and hundreds of requests per second), then it is not needed.

Comment: In this way if I've a day without records I get 1,1,1 when should be 1,0,1,1

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with Highcharts. I just saw several strange comments about PHP and wanted to help with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean something like php implode(), then try:

```
arrayName.join(delimiter);
```

Or simply loop array:

```
var str = '';
$.each(arrayName, function(i, num){
    str += num + ',';
})

str.slice(-1);
```